# Clickhouse can not find a proto message in schema file

Tags: prototype, clickhouse

We have a cluster of 2 clickhouse nodes. We use it for streaming from kafka, so we use kafka engine table. The data format is `proto` and we put each proto format in a specific folder in clickhouse.

The issue I am dealing with is:
I had an old proto, after a while  I should change the schema of data, so I removed the old kafka engine table and created a new one with the same table name. I also created a new folder and copied the new proto here, but I found that Clickhouse caches proto schema per table and didn't recognize the new proto path, so I created a new kafka engine table with different name, but this time Clickhouse found the proto filee but it rasied and error:

```
<Error> void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t): Code: 36. DB::Exception: Not found a     message named 'MyMessage' in the schema file 'test/my_message.proto': While executing Kafka. (BAD_ARGUMENTS), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
```

I wonder how to resolve this issues, should I delete cache, If so, where can I find the cache files path?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, I did these steps:

1. Change kafka engine table for example add a new version to it's name
2. Change consumer group name which should be specified in kafka engine table
3. Change the folder and proto file name(folder name change may not be needed)
4. Change the name of messages in proto file for example:

   message MESSAGE1{.....}

   message MESSAGE1 {.....}

Then change MESSAGE1 and MESSAGE2 wherever exists.
you don't need to change materialized view name (consumer name) and event the final table name.